# Hide windows in Dock that exist in different Space

Tags: dock, spaces

I use my laptop for both work and home use and am trying to improve logical separation of these purposes using spaces.

I have created two spaces, but have a problem where I accidentally switch back to the wrong space because the separation of windows is not sufficient.

For example, if I want to use a Firefox window, the dock lists all windows that exist irrespective of which space they are in. This means my personal and work windows are muddled up and easily confused.

[image: screenshot showing multiple firefox windows, muddled from multiple spaces into the same list]

In the above screenshot, the first and third window should show in Space 1, and the active window should be in Space 2 (because that is what I have open now and am in space 2).

Here's what I've done so far to improve separation:

- Disabled 'When switching to an application, switch to a Space ith open windows for the application'.
- Installed AltTab to change the cmd-tab shortcut to not show windows from other spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting a paradigm, I'm afraid.
macOS was never designed to use one app over more than one Space, and there's no native functionality to do what you require.

Probably the most efficient way to separate these pages is to use two different browsers. Otherwise, use key commands to go directly to a specific Space rather than one to go to a specific app.  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>[number]</kbd>  is the default key structure, they are generated automatically for each Space you add, but not enabled by default.

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control [up to Monterey, idk on Ventura]

[image]